# Aggregate multiple columns data while keeping same number of rows

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data:  (J-Job, T-Task, H-Hours)
Job consists of tasks which consists of hours

```
J     T      H  
1     1      5   
1     1      3  
2     2      4  
2     3      2
```

I want to get the following:  (S-for Job Hours Sum, P - Task Hours Sum)

```
J  S  T  P  H  
1  8  1  8  5   
1  8  1  8  3  
2  6  2  4  4  
2  6  3  2  2
```

What I mean is leaving the same data and in addition 2 columns:
1) for summarizing total job hours
2) for summarizing total task hours

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy using window functions. When you use `OVER (Partition BY)` you can use aggregate functions without changing other rows.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE ( J INT, T INT, H INT )

INSERT INTO @table
        ( J, T, H )
    VALUES  ( 1, 1, 5 )
    ,       ( 1, 1, 3 )
    ,       ( 2, 2, 4 )
    ,       ( 2, 3, 2 )

SELECT J
       ,SUM(h) OVER ( PARTITION BY j ) AS S
       ,T
       ,SUM(h) OVER ( PARTITION BY j, t ) AS S
       ,H
    FROM @table
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
SELECT  *,
        SUM(H) OVER (PARTITION BY J) S,
        SUM(H) OVER (PARTITION BY J, T) P
FROM    YourTable
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6205a/2)

Have a look at [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can through using window aggregate function

> select 
>        s= sum(h) OVER(PARTITION BY J)
>       ,t= sum(h) OVER(PARTITION BY J, T)
>       ,j
>       ,t
>       ,h from dbo.your's_table